# How to check if Redis is working on a shared server (without redis-cli)?

Tags: redis, shared-hosting

I host my website on a shared CentOS-Bash-Apache-MySQL-PHP server environment with Nginx as reverse proxy (Namecheap).

I understood that to enable Redis for my installment all I had to do was to add:

```
extension=redis.so
```

to:

```
$HOME/.system-php/ini/7.4/example.com/php.ini
```

I did that and saved the file but how can I test if Redis is working?

- I don't have `redis-cli` so I can't successfully run a command such as `redis-cli ping` (and get `PONG` back) on that particular environment

Comment: You can telnet to the redis port and type "PING<enter>"

Answer (score 0):

I understand that `phpinfo()` function can indicate if its installed AND enabled.

Here is the pattern I worked with in the SSH console:

```
$ cd ~
$ cd public_html
$ nano t.php
INPUTTED <?php phpinfo(); ?> AND SAVED THE FILE
RAN example.com/t.php IN MY WEB BROWSER
$ rm t.php
```

In PHP Info page I found:

> ### redis
>
> Redis Support enabled
> Redis Version 5.3.2
> Redis Sentinel Version 0.1